# getting gmsh into the virtualenv

Tags: python, pycharm, virtualenv

I'm extremely new to Python, so sorry if this is a stupid question. Anyways, I'm getting this error when trying to run a package I installed on PyCharm (Python IDE):

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\turtl\PycharmProjects\untitled\venv\Scripts\openbte-script.py", line 11, in <module>
    load_entry_point('openbte==0.9.24', 'console_scripts', 'openbte')()
  File "C:\Users\turtl\PycharmProjects\untitled\venv\lib\site-packages\openbte\__main__.py", line 47, in main
    Geometry(**vars(args))
  File "C:\Users\turtl\PycharmProjects\untitled\venv\lib\site-packages\openbte\geometry.py", line 83, in __init__
    data = self.compute_mesh_data()
  File "C:\Users\turtl\PycharmProjects\untitled\venv\lib\site-packages\openbte\geometry.py", line 91, in compute_mesh_data
    self.import_mesh()
  File "C:\Users\turtl\PycharmProjects\untitled\venv\lib\site-packages\openbte\geometry.py", line 448, in import_mesh
    a=subprocess.check_output(['gmsh','-' + str(self.dim),'mesh.geo','-o','mesh.msh'])
  File "C:\Users\turtl\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\subprocess.py", line 336, in check_output
    **kwargs).stdout
  File "C:\Users\turtl\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\subprocess.py", line 403, in run
    with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as process:
  File "C:\Users\turtl\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\subprocess.py", line 709, in __init__
    restore_signals, start_new_session)
  File "C:\Users\turtl\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\subprocess.py", line 997, in _execute_child
    startupinfo)
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified
```

From what I've gathered from previous questions, it seems this is because I don't have gmsh in my virtualenv. Now that I've downloaded gmsh, I can't find a proper installation guide on how to get it into the virtualenv. Does anyone have experience with this?

I guess more specifically, is there a way I can pinpoint the path that it's trying to access and just paste gmsh into that directory?

Answer (score 0):

`openbte\geometry.py` seems to run `gmsh.exe` without any path:

```
a=subprocess.check_output(['gmsh','-' + str(self.dim),'mesh.geo','-o','mesh.msh'])
```

Which means it expects `gmsh.exe` somewhere in the `%PATH%`. So install `gmsh` and add the directory with `gmsh.exe` to the `%PATH%`.